# Detect end of page and disable scrolling in AndroidPdfViewer

Tags: android, androidpdfviewer

I use https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer

I need to detect end of page, disable scrolling and make some validates.
How i can do it?

Answer (score 0):

As the PDFView consists of a Relative Layout, you could use the examples here: [How to get programmatically width and height of Relative - Linear layout in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20547974/how-to-get-programmatically-width-and-height-of-relative-linear-layout-in-andr) to get the size of the view.
Then you could get the current position from this view: [How to get absolute coordinates from Views in a RelativeLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738348/how-to-get-absolute-coordinates-from-views-in-a-relativelayout)
Maybe this can help you.